Docker ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
I'm running a python server on Docker and the ip address is 172.17.0.5 which is created by Docker.
The server code is:
HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) 
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECTED_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f" [NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT) #Here we define how many bytes we need to receive from the client
        # we are decoding the message from bytes to string with format utf-8
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECTED_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
            conn.send("Message received.".encode(FORMAT))
    conn.close()

def start(): #handle new connection
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTION {threading.activeCount() - 1}")

print("[STARTING] Server is starting... ")
start()

and the client code is:
import socket

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECTED_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #TCP
client.connect(ADDR)

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))

send("Hello Friend!")


I've tried to connect the client and the server but the connection is getting refused. I also tried to set the ip address to "127.17.0.5" instead of socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) but it still not working. How can I fix it?

The Docker-internal IP address is an implementation detail, and you should almost never need to know it.  How are you starting these two processes?  Which of them is in a container, and what options are you giving when they start these container(s)?  Do you know what address the server is binding to, and what address the client is trying to connect to?

First I'm starting the server in a container but the Client is running on the local host. No actually I don't know what address the server is binding to. The only configuration I have done in the docker file is: `FROM python
WORKDIR /Server
COPY . /Server
EXPOSE 5050
ENV NAME testserver
CMD ["python3", "-u", "Server.py"]`

The problem is fixed with three major changes I have made: 1. The first thing is that the IP address of the server should be "0.0.0.0" rather than SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) the internal IP-address in docker. 2. The second problem was not setting the port in running the docker. Instead of "docker run testserver" it should be "docker run -p 5050:5050 testserver" 3. The container should be stopped and run again to allocate the port again otherwise you will face with 'port is already allocated' error.
